# How to create path for restservice in codeigniter(rest_controller)

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, response, codeigniter-restserver

I am trying to create a studentdb in restful service in codeigniter(rest_controller). I had copied files like

```
Rest_contoller.php in libraries
Format.php in libraries
Rest.php in config and
rest_controller_lang.php in languages-english
```

when i am trying to check or load file getting error like

```
{"status":false,"error":"Unknown method"}
```

I think i forget to do something regarding the path creation. Can someone check it out please?

Comment: How are you checking the code using browser or postman?

Comment: hi....i am using browser

Comment: can you show the url here?